# Optional ManyToOne with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to create and Open Source library with JavBeans + Hibernate mappings that uses a provided database to read values (it only reads, no writes). Sadly, this database is not very well designed.

My problem is with a ManyToOne relationship that is optional - i.E. it can be null.

Here are the two tables (first is `types`, second is `metaTypes`):

```
+--------+---------------+
| typeID |   typeName    |
+--------+---------------+
|      1 | Chair         |
|      2 | Table         |
|      3 | Picnic Table  |
|      4 | Bedside Table |
+--------+---------------+

+--------+--------------+
| typeID | parentTypeID |
+--------+--------------+
|      3 |            2 |
|      4 |            2 |
+--------+--------------+
```

So, now there is the problem how this all belongs together. In the types table there are all kinds of types, like a list of things thet can exist.

In the second table those things are grouped together. As you can see, the "picnic table" has an entry in the `metaTypes` table as being a child of the type table.

If the type is a base type, there is no corresponding entry in the `metaTypes` table. In a well designed database, one would at least except there be exist an entry with NULL as `parentTypeID`, but it doesn't. I solved this by using `@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)` in the `Type` bean.

In the real database, there are more columns in the `metaType` table containing additional, relevant information, therefore I *must* have a `MetaType` bean.

After this lengthy introduction the real question occurs:
**How do I map a `Type` to it's variations (`MetaType`)?**

This is what I tried (shortened, getters & setters mostly ommited):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "types")
public class Type {

    @Id
    private int typeID;     
    private String typeName, description;

    // meta types/ variations

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "typeID", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = true)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private MetaType metaType; // -> this works as expected

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "typeID", referencedColumnName = "parentTypeID")
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private List<MetaType> variations; // this doesn't work

    /**
     * This method is quite easy to explain: Either this type is a base
     * type, in which case it has no metaType but holds the variations directly,
     * or it is a dervied type, in which case we get it's parent type and list the
     * variations of the parent type.
     */
    public List<MetaType> getVariations () {
        if (metaType != null) {
            return metaType.getParentType().getVariations();
        }
        return variations;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table (name = "metaTypes")
public class MetaType {

    @Id
    private int typeID;

    private Integer parentTypeID;

    // id <> object associations

    @OneToOne (mappedBy = "metaType")
    @JoinColumn(name = "typeID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Type type;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentTypeID", referencedColumnName = "typeID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Type parentType;
}
```

The goal should be clear. 
Let's say I query for the "Bedside Table". then metaType is not null but the variations list should be.

Let's say I queried for the "Table" type. In that case there is no MetaType and thanks to the `@NotFound` annotation, it silently fails and there is a null in the `metaType` field. So far, so good. But since "Table" has a `typeID` of `2` I would expect the `variations` list to include two entries. But instead I get the exception below.

But somehow this doesn't work, I get the below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1456)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindOneToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:864)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:779)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:728)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1695)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1424)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
```

So, what is wrong with the approach and how do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the following is the way I did and it seems to work fine:

**The Type Entity**

```
@Entity
public class Type {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "typeId")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="typeName")
    private String name;


    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="parentTypeId")
    List<MetaType> metaTypes;
}
```

Notice that my `@OneToMany` is not using a `mappedBy` attribute. In this case I am using `@JoinColumn` instead. This is a unidirectional relationship.

**The MetaType Entity**

```
@Entity
public class MetaType {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "typeId")
    private Type type;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentTypeId")
    private Type parentType;
}
```

Now, I recover a given type, like the example you gave and I get the right data:

```
TypeService service = ...;
Type t = service.getTypeById(2);

System.out.println(t.getName());
for(MetaType mt : t.getMetaTypes()){
    System.out.println("\t" + mt.getType().getName() + "-> " + mt.getParentType().getName());
}
```

This produces the output

```
Table
    Picnic Table-> Table
    Bedside Table-> Table
```

It also works correctly for types without variations. If you query for type 2 (chair), it will bring a Chair with empty variations collection, which I hope is what you were expecting.

Comment: Thanks, this is almost exactly what I needed. Using the non-existing id is quite an interesting trick ;) I ended up adding the Type -> MetaType one to one relationship also, because I need to be able to query for a bedside table, get the meta type, get the parent of it (Table) and then list the variations. But since i already have that working this solutions seems to be exactly what I need, i just tested it and so far it works fine.